# What is the difference between using backbone architecture and transfer learning?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, image-segmentation, transfer-learning, semantic-segmentation

hi im super new to this field(deep learning, computer vision)
so this question may sound dumb.

In this link (https://github.com/GeorgeSeif/Semantic-Segmentation-Suite), there are pre-trained models (eg, ResNet101) called front end models.  And they are used for Feature Extractor. I found these models are called backbone models/architectures generally. And the link says some of main models(eg. DeepLabV3, PSPNet) rely on pre-trained ResNet.
 Also, Transfer Learning is to take a model trained on a large dataset and transfer its knowledge to a smaller dataset, right ?

Then my question is ,
1.Do the models that rely on pre-trained ResNet do transfer learning basically ?
2.if i use pretrained network like ResNet101 as backbone architecture of main model(like U-Net,SegNet) for image segmentation, is it considered as transfer learning ?

Sorry for my bad english,and i would highly appreiate if you answer this questin. Thank you.

Comment: 1. unless its only used for resnet, then yeah. Trying to use another dataset/task taking advantage of already trained network in a similar task is transfer learning. 2. Yes, unlike the other cases where you probably only change last layer or two, here you add more but its same concept

Comment: This question is not about programming. Please ask at https://ai.stackexchange.com/. Thanks.

Comment: @juvian thanks for the reply! can I ask a question about the question 1 ? i read a paper PSPNet and there is no word " transfer learning" . so  are these models that rely on pre-trained models  considered as transfer learning in a 'broad sense' ? I mean i feel like the word 'transfer learning' is not defined strictly. Thank you though!

Comment: They mention they use a pretrained ResNet so they are applying transfer learning. Its  just not mentioned as its implied by the pretrained part. I recommend reading [standford summary](http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/)

Comment: @juvian thank you so much !!!  i apreciate you :)